# retrieving content within XML tags

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I've got a ver big XML with lots of information, I'm particularly interested in extracting the content of the following tags (config:tag1)

```
<config:tag1 var1="a" var2="b" var3="c"
    var4="d">
   <config:tag2 var5="abc" var6="def">
       <config:tag3 var7="foo1" var8="foo2" />
   </config:tag2>
</config:tag1>
<config:tag1 var1="h" var2="i" var3="j"
    var4="y">
   <config:tag2 var5="klm" var6="nop">
       <config:tag3 var7="foo3" var8="foo4" />
   </config:tag2>
</config:tag1>
<config:tag1 var1="m" var2="n" var3="o"
    var4="z">
   <config:tag2 var5="rop" var6="stv">
       <config:tag3 var7="foo5" var8="foo6" />
   </config:tag2>
</config:tag1>
```

I've tried with sed

`sed -n '/config:tag1/{s/.*<config:tag1>//;s/<\/config:tag1.*//;p;}' file.xml`

, awk

`awk -F "[><]" '/config:tag1/{print $3}' file.xml`

and grep

`grep -oP '(?<=<config:tag1>).*(?=</config:tag1)' file.xml`

with no success, what am I doing wrong?

expected output would be the lines with the all the content

```
<config:tag1 var1="a" var2="b" var3="c" var4="d">    <config:tag2 var5="abc" var6="def">    <config:tag3 var7="foo1" var8="foo2" /> 
  </config:tag2>    </config:tag1>
<config:tag1 var1="h" var2="i" var3="j" var4="y">    <config:tag2 var5="klm" var6="nop">    <config:tag3 var7="foo3" var8="foo4" /> 
   </config:tag2>    </config:tag1>
<config:tag1 var1="m" var2="n" var3="o" var4="z">    <config:tag2 var5="rop" var6="stv">    <config:tag3 var7="foo5" var8="foo6" /> 
   </config:tag2>    </config:tag1>
```

Comment: IMHO experts advise on SO to use tools like xmlstarlet which understand XML. Could you please do let us know if you could install it in your box? Solutions could be provided according to that, thank you

Comment: Some call it [summoning the daemon](https://www.metafilter.com/86689/), others refer to it as [the Call for Cthulhu](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) and few just [turned mad and met the Pony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8344060). In short, never parse XML or HTML with a regex! Did you try an XML parser such as `xmlstarlet`, `xmllint` or `xsltproc`?

Comment: I'm afraid is not possible to install an xml parser, this file is in a lot of boxes, so basically I'd be ssh'ing into these to retrieve this information

Comment: @javierccs, ok thanks for letting know. could you please explain logic more clearly like how you want to get sample expected output in your question as it is not clear, thank you.

Comment: @javierccs, Also tag `</config:tag1>` should come in next line because 2 of your shown output lines have it in same line and other 2 have them in next 2 lines, kindly confirm on same.

Comment: that's just a bad space as I was manually editing, I'm not sure how to get this output, I just posted the attempts I've done to get the content as these have failed, main point is that I need to be able to extract this information from these huge XMLs, obviously, the tags aren't adjacent to each other, these are scattered along the XML, but I just paste it like that to make it easier to read

Comment: @javierccs, if you could fix the samples(post them more clearly which gives us clear picture what you are trying to achieve) then it will be helpful for us to understand your question better.

Comment: I've fixed the samples, but I don't understand your question, what am I trying to achieve? well, obviously extract this information from a very big XML file?, just imagine this info is part of a huge XML and it's actually scattered on the XML, so from that XML I need the information within config:tag1

Comment: Perhap's try AWK's `match` function to extract only certain parts?

Comment: yep, that would be my first approach, but the problem is that var1, var2, etc.. are also present in other tags, so that's why I need to extract information only from within config:tag1

Comment: I have the impression you are a beginning programmer and some manager is forcing you to do this: you need to make them understand that, if someone chooses to use a certain technology (like XML in this case), that (s)he needs to accept the consequences, like in this case: accept that some tools are needed to parse that XML.

Answer (score 0):

If have had a similar problem myself.  My workaround is start newline when you see "<config:tag1" and print everything else on the same line

```
awk '{
  if(NR!=1 && $1 == "<config:tag1"){
    print ""
  }
  printf("%s ",$0)
}
END{
  print ""
}' file.xml
```

I tested this with your data and it worked